# Magento 2 How to Make 3rd party API request?

Tags: magento2, orders, api, rest-api, autoloader

I am trying to make a request to a third party webservice then using the response I would like to save the `data/order` in `Magento 2` using the `webApi`

My approach so far hasn't worked as Magento cannot find the class I am trying to autoload from the vendor folder:

Here is what I have so far:

In my webapi.xml file I've declared the classes and method to use for the request I want to make

```
<route method="GET" url="/V1/namespace-module/orders">
    <service class="Namespace\Module\Api\OrdersManagementInterface" method="createOrders"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

Then in the OrdersManagementInterface class

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Api;

use Third\Party\Library\Client\ShopApiClient;
use Third\Party\Library\Request\Order\Get\Request;

interface OrdersManagementInterface
{


    /**
     * GET for Orders api
     * @param array|Request $param
     * @param ShopApiClient $shopApiClient
     * @return array
     */

    public function createOrders(
        ShopApiClient $shopApiClient,
        Request $param
    );

    /**
     * PUT for Orders api
     * @param string $param
     * @return string
     */

    public function putOrders($param);
}
```

What I would like to do is call the third party service the save the response using the webapi but when I try to run the code using curl

`/index.php/rest/V1/namespace-module/orders` I get an error saying
`Class Third\Party\Library\Client\ShopApiClient does not exist`

Even though it is in the vendor folder - can anyone help?

Comment: You can explain more about `Third\Party\Library\Client\ShopApiClient` class?